# Switch between desktops in windows 7 when we pin many programs to taskbar

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, switching

When we pin many programs to the taskbar another desktop window is added which we can switch between them as you can see in the picture:

[image]

my question is how we can add them (without pinning the programs to taskbar) and Is there any shortcuts to switch between them?

Comment: Have you done any research to see if it is possible?

Comment: @CharlieRB , I've searched through internet but all the stuff I've found was about virtual desktop.

Comment: Are you sure what your image is pointing to is to scroll or view additional icons that won't fit on the taskbar? If so, that is not a desktop.

Comment: @CharlieRB,  no, I'm not. and I think you're right